# How to Equally Divide Discount on all Opportunity Values

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I am creating a plugin that will equally distribute the discount.  i want to equally divide the discount amount on all products.So if a product have price 2000 and other has 1000 so i want  to give discount 300 so it is divided by amount 200 should be give to 2000 and 100 to 100 in crm.

```
public class DivideEqualDiscount : IPlugin

{
    static IOrganizationService _service;
    public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {


        IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)
        serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

        ITracingService tracingService =


    (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));

        if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") &&
            context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
        {
            Entity target = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

            if (target.Attributes.Contains("new_amount"))
            {
                target["new_amount"] = "52";
            }
            if (target.Attributes.Contains("new_discount"))
            {
                target["new_discount"] = "52";
            }


            string fetchData = @"
               <entity name='opportunityproduct' >
               <attribute name='manualdiscountamount' />
               <attribute name='priceperunit' />
               <attribute name='volumediscountamount' />
               <attribute name='quantity' />
               <attribute name='extendedamount' />
               </entity>
              </fetch>";

            EntityCollection ec = ExecuteFetch(fetchData);
            foreach (var item in ec.Entities)
            {

                if (item.Attributes.Contains("msdyn_costpriceperunit"))
                {

                    target["new_discountamount"] = "";
                    target["new_discountpercentage"] = "";
                }
                if (item.Attributes.Contains("quantity"))
                {

                }
                if (item.Attributes.Contains("extendedamount"))
                {

                }

            }

        }

    }
    public static EntityCollection ExecuteFetch(string fetchXmlString)
    {
        return _service.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetchXmlString));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What have you tried. What issues are you experiencing?

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to calculate the percentage of the discount against the Opportunity total, then apply that percentage discount to each line.

For Example:

```
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public override void Run()
{            
    var totalDiscount = 200000;
    using (var ctx = new OrganizationServiceContext(svc))
    {
        var q = from l in ctx.CreateQuery("opportunityproduct")
                where l.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("opportunityid").Id.Equals(new Guid("D80E0283-5BF2-E311-945F-6C3BE5A8DD64"))                             
                select l;
        var lines = q.ToList();

        var total = lines.Sum(l => getLineTotal(l));
        var discountPercent = totalDiscount / total;

        lines.ForEach(l =>
        {
            var discount = discountPercent * getLineTotal(l);
            l["manualdiscountamount"] = new Money(discount);
            ctx.UpdateObject(l);
        });
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}

private decimal getLineTotal(Entity line) => 
    line.GetAttributeValue<Money>("priceperunit").Value * line.GetAttributeValue<decimal>("quantity");
```

Before:
[image: Before]

After applying $200,000 total discount:
[image: After]

Comment: You are right but I want to divide by percentage and by amount given by us. Let suppose that you want to give a discount of 5000 so it should divide to all products or if I add 10% that also apply